# Case-matching on `NS` type

Tags: haskell, generics-sop

The [`NS`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/sop-core-0.5.0.2/docs/Data-SOP.html#t:NS) type from `sop-core` creates an interesting conundrum. In `S :: NS f xs -> NS f (x ': xs)` where `xs ~ '[]` means that the argument to the `S` is inhabited. Yet Haskell's case matching forces me to match on it. Is there a resolution to this problem?

```hs
type T = NS I '[Int, String]

matchT :: T -> String
matchT = \case
  Z (I n) -> show n
  S (Z (I s)) -> s
  S (S _) -> error "FIXME" -- not reachable
```

If you remove that last case (which really shouldn't be necessary), Haskell complains "Pattern match(es) are non-exhaustive".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [`EmptyCase`](https://ghc.gitlab.haskell.org/ghc/doc/users_guide/exts/empty_case.html)!

```hs
matchT :: T -> String
matchT = \case
  Z (I n) -> show n
  S (Z (I s)) -> s
  S (S impossible) -> case impossible of {}
```

[Real-world example](https://github.com/srid/ema/pull/93/commits/12227d02b202d36901d744dfb41c1abf9499c0cb)

Comment: You might want to define `absurdNS :: NS f '[] -> a; absurdNS = \case`, it doesn't change anything but makes it a bit clearer and more uniform with `absurd :: Void -> a`.